# Programatically update an ACF field for all posts when an ACF options page is updated

Tags: php, database, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type set up with some ACF fields. I also have an ACF options page set up.

I'm trying to update a text field on all custom posts with a value from a text field within the options page, when the options page is updated.

Here's what I've tried:

```
function update_global_flash_text(){
    $current_page = get_current_screen()->base;
    if($current_page == 'toplevel_page_options') {
            function update_global_servicing_text() {
                $args = array(
                 'post_type' => 'custom',
                 'nopaging' => true,
                );

                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                     while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                         $the_query->the_post();
                         update_field('servicing_flash_text', $_POST['global_servicing_offer_text']);
                     }
                }

                wp_reset_postdata();
            }

            if(array_key_exists('post',$_POST)){
               update_global_servicing_text();
            }
        }
}
add_action('admin_head','update_global_flash_text');
```

Ideally I also want to only update the posts field if the global field value has changed.

Comment: Just to flip some logic, do you really need to update each CPT? Can you instead just pull from the Options on render? Depending on how many CPTs you have, updating each will eventually start slowing down over time, and could potentially timeout.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably looking for the `acf/save_post` hook. This is triggered whenever your ACF options page is getting saved. Just make sure that the current screen has the id of your options page.

```
function my_function() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    /*  You can get the screen id when looking at the url or var_dump($screen) */
    if ($screen->id === "{YOUR_ID}") {
        $new_value = get_field('global_servicing_offer_text', 'options');
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'custom',
            'nopaging' => true,
        );
        
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $the_query->the_post();
                update_field('servicing_flash_text', $new_value);
            }
        }
        
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_function');
```

Does that get you anywhere?

EDIT:
Since you asked to only update data if the global value has changed, you should do the following:

1 Give your `acf/save_post` action a priority higher than 10:

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_function', 5);
```

2 Get the old and new value:

```
$old_value = get_field('global_servicing_offer_text', 'options');
// Check the $_POST array to find the actual key
$new_value = $_POST['acf']['field_5fd213f4c6e02'];
```

3 Compare them `if($old_value != $new_value)`